# rsync ignores some folders at /mnt without reasons

Tags: rsync, backup

I'm trying to do a full backup of my system with rsync.

Structure:

- the source is: `/`
- and the destination is : `/mnt/rsync_backup`: an internal drive dedicated only for this rsync backup, automatically mounted
- `/mnt/other_folder`: a NTFS partition, automatically mounted . It should be backed up also.

I do:

`rsync --stats --delete --stats -avxqhHAX --exclude '/mnt/rsync_backup' / /mnt/rsync_backup`

(of course I'm excluding the destination folder to avoid an endless loop)

Rsync is running without error (using `sudo`). But everything under `/mnt/other_folder` is ignored (with no errors at the end of rsync):

the `/mnt/rsync_backup/mnt/other_folder` is created but is empty.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used `-x` with `rsync`:

> `-x`, `--one-file-system`
>
> This tells `rsync` to avoid crossing a filesystem boundary when
>                 recursing.

This is why it avoids going into `/mnt/other_folder` (it's on another filesystem).

---

You also seem to use both `-v` (`--verbose`) and `-q` (`--quiet`).  The `-q` flag will override the `-v` flag.

You may want to additionally exclude other folders, such as `/dev`, from your backup.